# How to unmark a question marked as duplicate?

Tags: support, reopen-request

This question:

[0xc000000f BCD error in windows 10... Nothings working](https://superuser.com/questions/1211487/0xc000000f-bcd-error-in-windows-10-nothings-working)

was marked as duplicate by several members.

I think it is not an exact duplicate as there are differences in Windows 7 and Windows 10 boot process. At least there is the new "Metro" or graphical/immersive boot menu which is implemented through several dll-files non-existent in Windows 7. There are also new BCD elements specific to Windows 10, not to mention widely used UEFI firmware on newer computers.

As a consequence Windows 10 boot manager is different and some boot errors are different. You cannot transfer one to one old solutions to boot problems for Windows 7 to Windows 10. There are also changes in Windows loader, kernel etc.

Comment: I've reopened it for you.

Comment: You normally would modify the question if you were the author.  In this process the question is put into a queue asking if the question should be reopended if you are the author.  If you are an editor/reviewer then you would vote to reopen and/or flag it for a moderators attention if your below the required reputation to vote to reopen it yourself

Answer (score 7):

If you believe a question is incorrectly marked as a duplicate, you can vote to reopen it (since you're a >3K user) using the "reopen" link below it. Five reopen votes will undo the closure. Casting one such vote pushes the question into the [Reopen Votes](https://superuser.com/review/reopen) queue, where other >3K users will examine it and decide whether reopening is warranted. If your reason for it not actually being a duplicate might not be obvious to others, you should leave a comment on the question.

Further reading: [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://superuser.com/help/reopen-questions)